# Java 6 Socket Garbage Collected

Tags: java, sockets, garbage-collection

Quick question:

If a Socket object (and its locally cached InputStream and OutputStream objects) falls out of scope and is garbage collected, does the connection remain open in the JVM?  (I.e., no EOFException would be thrown on the listening server)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a finalizer (of *some* object related to the socket) will end up closing the socket... at least in any sane implementation, IMO, just like any other non-memory resource (file handles etc). This will happen at the whim of the garbage collector's timing though - I would treat this as a programming error, effectively.

Comment: Sorry for asking this after 2 years, but can you suggest some good practices to prevent this :)